# Preserve order of closing services while shutting down the Linux

Tags: linux, systemd, shutdown, reboot

I defined a Linux `systemd` service which has few dependencies in unit file using `After=` and `Requires=`. My service depends also on SAN filesystems controlled by Veritas.

When stopping my service upon shutdown I noticed my service is stopped after VCS service which prevents my service from stopping gracefully (as it requires filesystems controlled by Veritas to stop which are not present).

I have following dependencies set:

```
[unit]
After=vcs.service vxfs.service vxvm-boot.service
Requires=vcs.service vxfs.service vxvm-boot.service
```

Any idea how can I set the right order during shutdown to call my service before Veritas services and which Veritas services I should depend on?

Answer (score 0):

From the [official docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html),

> When two units with an ordering dependency between them are shut down,
> the inverse of the start-up order is applied. I.e. if a unit is
> configured with After= on another unit, the former is stopped before
> the latter if both are shut down.

Given what you have documented in your .service file, the services should be shut down in the proper order.